# `Model.deploy()` failing for AutoML with `400 'automatic_resources' is not supported for Model`

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Trying to use the python SDK to deploy an AutoML model, but am recieving the error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 'automatic_resources' is not supported for Model
```

Here's what I'm running:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

aiplatform.init(project="MY_PROJECT")

# model is an AutoML tabular model
model = aiplatform.Model("MY_MODEL_ID")

# this fails
model.deploy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encounter the `automatic_resources` because deploying models for AutoML Tables requires the user to define the machine type at model deployment. See [configure compute resources for prediction docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/configure-compute#specify) for more information.

> If you want to use a custom-trained model or an AutoML tabular model
> to serve online predictions, you must specify a machine type when you
> deploy the Model resource as a DeployedModel to an Endpoint.

You should add defining of resources to your code for you to continue the deployment. Adding `machine_type` parameter should suffice. See [supported machine types docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/configure-compute#machine-types) for complete list.

See code below:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

project = "your-project-id"
location = "us-central1"
model_id = "99999999"

aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location)
model_name = (f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}")

model = aiplatform.Model(model_name=model_name)

model.deploy(machine_type="n1-standard-4")

model.wait()
print(model.display_name)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: awesome, thanks! I for some reason mistakenly thought that machine type didn't have to be specified for AutoML deployments